# Calculating $\int_{\gamma}f$ in $G = \{z : 0 < |z| < 1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $G = \{z : 0 < |z| < 1\}$ and $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ be analytic. Suppose $\gamma $ is closed rectifiable curve in $G$ such that $n(\gamma,a)=0$ for all $a$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus G$. What is $\int_{\gamma}f$?

Here's what I have thought.

-The value is trivially $\int_{\gamma}f=Res(f,0)\cdot 2\pi i$, but I assume the problem asks for an especific answer.

-If we had $\{z :  |z| < 1\}$ instead of $\{z : 0 < |z| < 1\}$, by Cauchy's theorem we would have $\int_{\gamma}f=0$. Of course we can't apply this because $f$ could have either a pole or an essential singularity at $z=0$.

Is there even an especific answer? I would say it depends of $f$, but maybe the integral is just zero.

Any hints?

Comment: The answer is $0$ by Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: But can you apply Cauchy's theorem in a punctured disk? @zhw.

Comment: You can apply Cauchy to any contour that winds around no point of the complement of the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U := \{z : |z| < 1\}$ is simply connected and $f$ holomorphic
in $G = U \setminus \{ 0 \}$.
According to the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem),
$$
\int_{\gamma}f(z) \, dz = 2 \pi i \, n(\gamma, 0) \, Res(f, 0)
$$
and that is zero because $n(\gamma, 0) = 0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wasn't applying the residue theorem correctly. Thank you!